# The right way to use fineOne(), find() functions in Monk

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, monk

I am building an RESTful API using expressjs and Monk. There's a requirement where I should grab several documents from different collections (One-to-Many). But I'm not sure how to implement it.

For example, I need to grab one car information from the Cars collection, and 4 wheels from Wheels collection. I know that I should use findOne() to find the car, and from there I can access the type of wheels.

The Code would be something like this

```
var wheelType;
cars.findOne({_id: "C300"}).then((car) => {
  wheelType = car["wheeltype"];
})
```

Here's the point. I now have the car information, but I couldn't define a variable outside of the scope to save the value, and start a new find() function to collet the information for wheels.

Surely, I can try to do everything in .then() just like this

```
cars.findOne({_id: "C300"}).then((car) => {
  wheels.findOne({type: car["wheeltype"][0] }).then((wheel) => {
    // combind the car with wheel
  })
})
```

but, what if I have more details to collect? do I just nest the findOne() function?

I might be fitting the MySQL idea wrongly to MongoDB (there's some other way to implement the One-to-Many mapping?). I am expecting something like this:

collection cars we have

```
{
  {
    name:"c300",
    wheeltype:["A","B","C"]
  }
  {
    name:"R100",
    wheeltype:["E","F","C"]
  }
}
```

collection wheels we have

```
{
  {
    type:"A",
    Brand:"BestWheel"
  }
  {
    type:"C",
    Brand:"GoodWheel"
  }
}
```

and after the manipulation, I have this as output

```
{
   name:"c300",
   wheel:{
           Brand:"BestWheel",
           type:"A"
          }
}
```

Comment: If I'm correct you have an array of objects, right? In Mongo, that is.

Comment: Yes, I probably should have used `[<Wheel>...]` to represent it. I am simplifying the question here, but for the most of my code, the elements in the arrays are just the ObjectID that points to documents in other collections

Comment: Would you mind updating the object then? I think it's easier than you think, but you need to do a few things to simplify your life. From what I understand, Each type is related to a brand, right? e.g. type A is BestWheel. Also, second question, can you modify the objects in Mongo or are they set and you just have to collect data from them?

Comment: I think I misunderstood you. When you say object, I assume that you are talking about the documents in a collection. Then, my question would have been "How do we do Object Relational Mapping in Monk. Is it still ok to change the content in a question? I can only change very little in the Mongo since the structure is in the requirement specification.

Comment: Sorry for not responding I was sick yesterday. Did you manage to solve it? If not I'll help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I find it reasonable to nest the findOne() function since it is an asynchronous call back function. Then for this question if you want to implement something like the requirement, nested is necessary.

```
cars.finOne(...).then((car) =>{
  wheels.findOne(...).then((wheel) =>{
    // create a json that contains wheels in a car object.
  }
}
```